# Graph API: Retrieve all public posts re-shared by a user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need a way to retrieve all public posts re-shared by a specific user. I'm trying to get a list of all posts re-shared by my friends. Please look at this [example](http://i39.tinypic.com/20i8cqw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any API to return this specifically; though you could pull a user's updates from the API (/USER_ID/feed) and find those posts which have an item from another page attached,

e.g. I shared a Photo from a Page onto a Friend's Timeline, and when i retrieve it from the API it has this structure identifying the original source:

```
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "By", 
      "text": "Black Dynamite", 
      "href": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Black-Dynamite/47850309260"
    }
```

Perhaps you could use that to see the original source of reshared items on a user's timeline?

Comment: My friend has shared on his wall a public post (created by his friend). The /USER_ID/feed API does not seem to retrieve such posts when the USER_ID is the my friend's UID.